# Empty entity syntax

Tags: php

I'm attempting to display a piece of text only if two fields contain a value, but I'm a little unfamiliar with the correct php syntax in this case. The error complained about here is an unexpected ':'

This works

```
<?php if (!empty($entity->directory_contact[0]['website'])):?>
```

This does not

```
<?php if ((!empty($entity->directory_contact[0]['website']) and (!empty($entity->directory_contact[0]['email'])):?>
<div>Hello World</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing some round brackets, this should fix it

```
 if ((!empty($entity->directory_contact[0]['website'])) and (!empty($entity->directory_contact[0]['email'])))
                                                   //^1 here 
                                                                                                          //^1 here
```